# How can i secure my application and also protect my Sqlite database in application

Tags: android, encryption, database-project, android-security, data-protection

How can i secure my application and also protect my database in application. Which means data is not accessed by other application or by reverse engineering. Like in banking application login data and other information is stored in app but we can not accessed. How to achieve this type of security in application.
Encryption is way to achieve security but there are many types of encryption. I am not getting to figured out that which encryption type is better for security in application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sqlcipher to protect your sqlite database 
[click here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher)

Comment: Thanks Pratik. But Encryption is based on key so key will be used in code which will be hard coded. so other people can be decrypted by key easily.

Comment: you can put the key in string resource

Comment: @ShashankGupta put key in ndk